# HTML5: How to set focus on a text input in a list with AngularJS

Tags: html, input, focus, angularjs

I use AngularJS with the ng-repeat directive to show an array of objects as a list.

```
<li ng-repeat="cue in cues" class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" ng-model="cues[$index].text" class="input-xlarge"/>
    {{cue.isNewest}}
</li>
```

The property "isNewest" is true on only one element of the array. I would like to set the keyboard focus on the text input of that item. How can I do that with AngularJS?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is another directive implementation that uses attrs.$observe:

```
myApp.directive('focus', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('focus', function (newValue) {
      newValue === 'true' && element[0].focus();
      // or, if you don't like side effects (see @Christophe's comment):
      //if(newValue === 'true')  element[0].focus();
    });
  }
});
```

Note that an interpolated DOM attribute value (i.e., `{{cue.isNewest}}`) always evaluates to a string, hence the reason `newvalue` is compared to the string `'true'` rather than keyword `true`.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cues[$index].text" focus="{{cue.isNewest}}"
 class="input-xlarge" />{{cue.isNewest}}
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/Xktuz/) also has a method to toggle which item in the array should have the focus.

Note that if you do not load jQuery, we need to use `element[0].focus()` in the link function (not `element.focus()`) becaues jqLite doesn't have a focus() method.

Comment: Accepted over asgoth's answer, because it worked the first time tried and is well expalined.

Comment: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`: I must say I have not seen a side-effect in an expression for years except in some one-liner contests, it should be 'if (cond) {focus here}'.

Answer (score 4):

Since you would be manipulating the DOM, you will need to create a directive. Something like:

```
var app = angular.module('quirli', []);
app.directive('focusable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            focusable: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('focusable', function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    elm[0].focus();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Html:**

```
<html ng-app="quirli" lang="en">
....  
<input type="text" ng-model="cues[$index].text" class="input-xlarge" focusable="{{cue.isNewest}}"/>
```

**Note:** untested.

Comment: Tanks asgoth for this piece of code. I have slightly modified it, added an app name, as shown here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive The focusing stuff now works, the problem now is that the text in the textboxes is omitted. I have to figure out what the cause is for that.

Comment: I'm now reading through the mentioned directive document. Twists my mind!

Comment: Use elm[0].focus() if jQuery is not loaded (well, even if it is loaded, it might be better to use this syntax, as it should always work).

Comment: Works OK ...unless you also use ng-focus / ng-blur. Then you'll run into "$digest already in progress" territory.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special feature in AngularJS to receive focus. You could solve this with a $watch in your controller, but also with a directive.

Comment: I have looked into $watch, from here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope However, I come to the conclusion that I can only watch changes of the model. But my controller would not be able to manipulate the DOM, nor is this good design, AFAIK.

Comment: The controller would be able to manipulate the dom, but it's not good design. So a directive it is for you :)

Answer (score 1):

The other proposed answers work OK 9/10 times for me, but soon I was running in "$digest already in progress" fun.

I have a slightly modified version of the previous answers by asgoth and Mark Rajcok. Basically you inject the $timeout dependency and put the focus() call inside of a timeout(...). IIRC ng-focus does the same.

```
var app = angular.module('cgeers', []);
app.directive('focus', ["$timeout", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.focus, function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    $timeout(function() { element[0].focus(); });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```