# AngularJS: attrs.$observe not firing after the first time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/thatmarvin/6vfGm/)

In the fiddle, if you click on the submit button for the first time, notice that the `<input>` correctly gets focused on. On subsequent clicks, the focus isn't set any longer.

I noticed that the `$observe` callback isn't getting triggered when `submit()` changes `isFocused`, so I added a `blur` listener to explicitly reset the variable but that didn't help either.

How do I make the focus stick on submit?

**Edit**: [Final working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thatmarvin/e9H5x/). Using `$watch` instead because I want it to work with arbitrary expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you watch the element you'll notice that when the blur callback is fired the `focus-on` attribute isn't set to false. The reason for this is that the `blur` function is outside angular's scope and so it isn't aware of changes you make inside it.

To make angular aware of the change you need wrap any changes inside a call to [$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)

```
element.bind('blur', function () {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.isFocused = false;
        console.log('blur');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6vfGm/7/

Comment: D'oh. I was well aware of this $apply thing, but totally overlooked it while I was trying out a bunch of other stuff. Thanks!

Comment: +1, well spotted. I'm still not sure this $observe way is best though, seems to me $broadcast/$on gives the same result in shorter, more maintainable code. I'm open to be convinced if there's a reason I'm missing though!

Comment: @mikel I actually stole the $observe thing from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14205885/457519, but see my final solution using $watch instead: http://jsfiddle.net/thatmarvin/e9H5x/. I prefer not using events because I've ran into several instance when things fail silently because of mismatched event strings. At least you'll see errors when variables are undefined. Plus I don't want to hardcode the event strings because I have other reasons to focus on a field besides  submitting an empty form. Just doesn't seem like a suitable use of events here.

Comment: Fair enough. Interesting to see the different approaches anyway.

Comment: It's a good thing that you can look to this implementation, it seems to be a good approach to implment ngBlur and ngFocus. https://gist.github.com/eliotsykes/5394631

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can observe the `focusOn` attribute because it doesn't really exist as an attribute of the directive. When you do `<input focus-on='{{isFocused}}' />` the `focus-on` is actually your directive name.

Try this instead:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='foo'>
    <form ng-controller='FormCtrl' ng-submit='submit()'>
        <input focus-on focused='isFocused' />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
app.directive('focusOn', function () {
    return {
        scope: { focused: '=' },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('focused', function (newValue) {
                console.log('$watch', newValue)
                if (newValue) {
                    element[0].focus();                    
                }
            });

            element.bind('blur', function () {
                scope.focused = false;
                scope.$apply(); // required so that the scope is updated correctly.
                console.log('blur');
            });
        }
    };
});

app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.isFocused = true;
        console.log('submit');
    };
});
```

I created a `focused` attribute to bind the `isFocused` property to the directive scope (I could have named it `focusOn`, but I guess it would be weird to have `<input type="text" focus-on focus-on="isFocused" />`).

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/6vfGm/5/) your updated jsFiddle.

**Update**: I changed the attribute name from `ng-model` to `focused` so it makes more sense.

Comment: Not sure about this because I need ng-model to represent the actual value in the form field. Say when ng-model='email', it doesn't make sense to do $scope.email = true.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, you can just pick another name for the attribute.

Comment: I've just changed the attribute name to `focused`. Makes more sense now.