# Loading jquery is must in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Am trying to manipulate dom by using jquery in angularjs; As per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

"If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function.
 If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

I have two links one [using jquery](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sn0X1aZf1CX5dBVo2kq0?p=preview) works and one [without using jquery](http://plnkr.co/edit/BtnUW243uvLXqj785NIw?p=preview) throws error.
Needed some suggestion on how to get this working without declaring jquery externally?

Comment: If you're using JQuery functionality you need to load it. Not sure what exactly it is you're asking here?

Comment: @ivarni : I don't want to load jquery; Angular has built-in subset jqLite can't we make use of it and get it working?

Comment: Not if you're going to use selectors with id. Are you asking how to set focus on an element without using JQuery?

Comment: `without using jquery throws error` What error to be precise?

Comment: `Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element`

Comment: Am working focus and circular tab feature in angular; As we have already have working examples in jquery just wanted to make use of it in angular;

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-in-angularjs and see if some of the answers are useful.

Comment: how about if we need keypress events for tab functionality to work in angular?

Comment: I don't know how the error message, and the documentation, could be clearer. angular.element() doesn't allow getting an element by ID. This is the documented behavior. The documentation also clearly explains that manipulating the DOM from controllers is a big no-no. Directives should be used to do that.

Comment: @JBNizet : Yup! got it... was just trying to manipulate dom using angularjs;

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Angular's jQlite supports the .focus() shortcut - jQlite is only a subset of jQuery see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element for a list of jQlite methods.

You need to call focus on element[0].focus as per this stackoverflow answer [HTML5: How to set focus on a text input in a list with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204446)

Answer (score -1):

You can read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) the methods that jqLite provide.
In this particular case you could write something like this.

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

app.controller('myappCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {

  $timeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('number').focus()
  }, 1);

 angular.element(document.getElementById('focusguard-2')).on('focus', function() {
    document.getElementById('number').focus();
  });

  angular.element(document.getElementById('focusguard-1')).on('focus', function() {
    document.getElementById('cancel').focus()
  });

});
```

Comment: I would try to avoid doing any UI logic in the controllers - I would try this into a directive