# AngularJS .focus() not working within link function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why is it that if I have the following directive it works:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('selectOnFocus', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element){
                element[0].focus(); 
            }
        };
    });
```

But if I switch it to this, it says element.focus() is not a function. To get this code to work, I need to import jquery in my index.html.

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('selectOnFocus', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element){
                element.focus(); 
            }
        };
    });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here" select-on-focus >
    <hr>
    <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204446/html5-how-to-set-focus-on-a-text-input-in-a-list-with-angularjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is, why does your code work with element[0].focus(), but not with element.focus(). The answer, as indicated by @mcranston18's comment, is element returns a jqLite object. Refer to the docs for directives [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), and jqLite elements [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) for a deeper understand of what that means. Also, a simple console log of the element object, in the updated jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rmra3cso/1/, shows what's inside the jqLite object.

In short, when you include jQuery and call `element.focus()`, you are using the jQuery focus method. When you use `element[0].focus()`, you are accessing the DOM element itself and using pure JavaScript. I suggest not using jQuery with Angular, and getting used to using jqLite. You'll find you probably won't need jQuery with Angular.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So to access the direct DOM element its always just element[0]? In what instance would there be more than one item in the element array?

Comment: According to the docs, "element is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches." Therefore, in your case, you will always get one jqLite-wrapped element in the link function.

Comment: I tried to use element[0].focus() but when running tests I got something like "focus is not a function". But it works like a charm if I use element[0].select(). Do you know why I get this error?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `focus()` is *not* supported in jqLite and from the angular docs on [element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

> If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's
>   built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."